# Front-running attack for staking deposit is not a concern?

Tags: staking, frontrunning

The front-running attack for Eth staking deposit is a widely known issue.
The delegated staking protocols have their own remedy to mitigate the issue.

As a solo home staker, I am still vulnerable to this front-running attack.

- someone can see my validator public key in the txn mempool
- they can front-run my txn and set my validator node's withdrawal address to his one

I know that they don't have much economical incentive to do so because they don't have the validator private key and, thus, cannot exit the fund.

It seems the entire Eth community is aware of this issue, but is not handling it nor giving any warnings, for example, here? https://ethereum.org/en/staking/

Do we just think it's such a rare case?